Why does the peak of quasar distribution move from near to far with increasing magnitude?
I made a little tool to examine the distribution of quasars in various catalogs, including SDSS DR16Q:
If you check the +/- box, and move the magnitude slider from low (-20) to high (-30), the peak of the quasars moves from z=0 to about z=3.3.
Here're the results summarized:

One obvious factor is that the quasars on the dimmer end won't show up at high-z, simply because they're too dim*. And very bright quasars ceased to exist recently.
But can that really explain this picture?
Is there something else going on? Seems odd the peak would move so linearly with magnitude.

Edit:
GN-z11 has an estimated absolute magnitude of -22.1. So if there were quasars of that magnitude we should be able to detect them out to z=11.
https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.3847/0004-637X/819/2/129
But quasars of that magnitude don't exist at z > 1.6.

